# Sintaxis inválida en script Python (web scraping)

Tags: python, scraping

Estoy intentado probar un poquito este tema del "web scraping" con Python, pero al ejecutar el script que os pongo más abajo me dice:

```
>!{sys.executable} -m pip install beautifulsoup4
>^
>SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Código:

```
import urllib.request
datos = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.es.stackoverflow.com').read().decode();
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install beautifulsoup4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(datos)
tags = soup('a')
for tag in tags:
    pring(tag.get('href'))
```

El error me lo señala en el `!` símbolo de exclamación y la verdad es que no tengo nada de idea de Python pues hace mucho que no he tocado nada de eso. ¿Una ayuda?

Comment: Estas usando jupyter notebook ? ,

Comment: uso nano de ubuntu

Comment: prueba `pip install` `modulo` desde la consola

Comment: Esa línea que te da error no tiene sintaxis python. Borrala, quita el `import sys` que no sería necesario, e instala beautifulsoup desde una terminal de Ubuntu. La forma de instalarlo es `pip install beautifulsoup4`, pero eso (probablemente) intentará instalarlo a nivel de sistema y no te dejará a menos que lo hagas con `sudo`. Esto de todas formas no es recomendable, pues deberías evitar instalar cosas a nivel de sistema, pudiendo hacerlo localmente usando `virtualenv`. Pero creo que esto se sale del alcance de la pregunta.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que sucede es que con esta parte del código:

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Estás intentando instalar el paquete `beautifulsoup4`. La verdad no tengo idea en que contexto eso funcionaría (tal vez jupyter, como mencionó @Lucas-damian).

Lo que debes hacer es instalar `beautifulsoup4`. Puedes usar `sudo -H pip install beautifulsoup4` y retirar el intento de instalación de tu código.

**NOTA**: Respecto a la instalación que te sugiero (con `sudo` y `pip`) no es lo más apropiado, pero como estás empezando creo que bastará. Una forma más apropiada y elegante de manejar las dependencias es usando entornos virtuales para cada aplicacion/proyecto que desarrolles (virtualenv, como lo mencionó @abulafia), ya veras su utilidad a medida que progreses con Python.